# Cannot compile Rcpp (can't find header)

Tags: r, linux, gcc, compilation, rcpp

I was trying to install Rcpp in R through `install.packages("Rcpp")`, but the following error occurred:

```
* installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
** package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -I/home/jerry/local/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -diag-disable 308 -c Date.cpp -o Date.o
g++: 308: No such file or directory
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: i
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: g
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: -
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: d
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: i
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: s
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: b
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: l
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: e
make: *** [Date.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
* removing ‘/home/jerry/r-lib/Rcpp’
* restoring previous ‘/home/jerry/r-lib/Rcpp’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpfxSJDZ/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("Rcpp") :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status
```

It looks like a compiling problem to me (who do not know much about compiling software), but I have no idea how to solve it. I checked the file Rcpp/src/Date.cpp. It has the following include lines:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <time.h>   
#include <Rcpp/exceptions.h>
```

Rcpp.h and Rcpp/exceptions.h are both in `Rcpp/inst`, which should have been included in the searching path `-I../inst/include/`. I have no idea where `time.h` is.

I'm using a cluster that I do not have root access to. I downloaded R-3.2.3 and compiled on my own using the following method:

```
./configure --prefix=~/local
make
make install
```

I was able to install Rcpp with the version of R (3.2.1) offered by the system. All my packages are in ~/r-lib.

I would appreciate any help or hints. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have something in `.Rprofile` that prints to the screen? That '308' messing things up has to come from somewhere -- and it's not us.

Comment: One thing you should do is fix the warnings from the preprocessor. Get rid of that `-diag-disable 308`. Grep the source files and then delete it. It is probably in `Makefile.am` somewhere. After editing `Makefile.am`, you may need `autoreconf -f -i` (or set the time back on `Makefile.am` so it does not look edited/newer than other files).

Comment: There is no reason why `configure --prefix=...` and setting `R_LIB*` can't work; I do the same for the r-devel installation I also keep on my machine.